# Informix database versioning

Tags: informix, database-versioning

I'm trying to figure out IBM Informix database versioning, or release naming conventions. I'm trying to map out the differences between minor versions and fixpacks.
According to [IBM's own documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.mig.doc/ids_mig_022.htm), the convention is:
X.Y.C. 
But I'm looking at [Informix version 12.10 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.po.doc/new_features_ce.htm#newxc9__xc9_push_data) and the list of "what's new in " looks more like a list of new features rather than bug fixes.

So what's the difference between a minor version and a fixpack??
IBM documentation is godawful and no amount of keyword googling helped me.

Thanks!

Comment: This technote talks about the version number and suffixes, it may help  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21171814.  In terms of what was fixed in each specific version,
best way is to go to the IBM support page (e.g. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27049036)
and search for "Fix list for Informix Server"

Comment: In theory, new features are introduced in new versions, but periodically Informix goes into stasis on the version number.  Version 12.10 has been the 'current' version for quite a while now, but new features have been added, so 'fix packs' have been used as minor versions.  It's not good, but it is an internal political game that complicates the life of developers.

Comment: Thank you Johnathan and J_S!